# Errors in file Styles.xml

Tags: xml, styles, android-actionbar, light

i'm working on a project that was given to me,
it all fine, except for some errors in the styles.xml file:

file: res/values-v11/styles.xml

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@drawable/actionbar_shadow</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#eee</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitle</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_home</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_title_color</item>
</style>
```

give me that errors:

*error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:style/Theme.Holo.Light'.
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionBarStyle'.
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar'.
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:titleTextStyle'.*

and file: res/values-v13/styles.xml

```
<style name="ActionBarTitle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_title_color</item>
</style>
```

give thah other error:

*error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.*

Someone can help me to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem when setting up my project in Eclipse. This is an issue with the Google API that your project is targeting. I'm betting this will fix it:

Look in the project.properties file located in the main directory of your project. The target should be:

```
target=android-16 (or Google Inc.:Google APIs:16)
```

I'm betting yours is target=android-8 (Google Inc.:Google APIs:8)? If this does not fix the issue please share your uses-sdk block located in your android manifest so we can troubleshoot from there. It should look something like this:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Hope this helps